# How to get more accuracy in imbalanced binary time series classifier

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, time-series, classification

I am new to machine learning and I am working on a problem of sequence classification.
The data in the dataset consists of sequences of shape(20,9)
9 features of length 20.

I have tried below model but I have failed to get good accuracy.

```
f = 32
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 4*f, activation='tanh', return_sequences = True, input_shape = (window_length, 9)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 4*f, activation='tanh', return_sequences = True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 4*f, activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 256, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', TP, TN, FP, FN])
model.build()
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=256, batch_size=256, callbacks=[WeightsSaver(model,1)], validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

I have also tried more deep network, CNN_LSTMs and CNN_LSTM with dense layers at the end.

I am not getting good confustion matrix. It is mostly giving me false negatives even on train set.
I have also tried to balance the data using SMOTE and SVM_SMOTE still it is giving me low accuracy.

The problems I am facing:

1)Without resampling: majority class prevails and very less minority class.

2)With resampling: I am getting many false positives on train and test data.

I have pasted the data on below kaggle page.

https://www.kaggle.com/jgranth/binary-seqclassification-of-input-shape209

Can someone expert in this field help to share experiences and possible solution or point out mistakes that I could be making.

Below is the output I am getting on train without resampling.

```
Epoch 1/256
2602/2602 [==============================] - 143s 48ms/step - loss: 0.4011 - accuracy: 0.8606 - TP: 4.3987e-04 - TN: 0.8601 - FP: 7.5963e-04 - FN: 0.1387 - val_loss: 0.4525 - val_accuracy: 0.8285 - val_TP: 5.8129e-04 - val_TN: 0.8281 - val_FP: 5.8710e-04 - val_FN: 0.1708
Epoch 2/256
2602/2602 [==============================] - 122s 47ms/step - loss: 0.3956 - accuracy: 0.8609 - TP: 3.2877e-04 - TN: 0.8605 - FP: 3.4228e-04 - FN: 0.1388 - val_loss: 0.4554 - val_accuracy: 0.8285 - val_TP: 0.0000e+00 - val_TN: 0.8286 - val_FP: 5.2316e-05 - val_FN: 0.1713
Epoch 3/256
2602/2602 [==============================] - 123s 47ms/step - loss: 0.3937 - accuracy: 0.8609 - TP: 4.1434e-04 - TN: 0.8605 - FP: 3.8132e-04 - FN: 0.1387 - val_loss: 0.4495 - val_accuracy: 0.8285 - val_TP: 8.7193e-05 - val_TN: 0.8286 - val_FP: 6.9754e-05 - val_FN: 0.1713
Epoch 4/256
2602/2602 [==============================] - 122s 47ms/step - loss: 0.3926 - accuracy: 0.8610 - TP: 5.7198e-04 - TN: 0.8604 - FP: 4.8640e-04 - FN: 0.1385 - val_loss: 0.4479 - val_accuracy: 0.8289 - val_TP: 0.0016 - val_TN: 0.8275 - val_FP: 0.0012 - val_FN: 0.1698
```

Comment: Have you looked into sample weighting and class weighting? https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#class_weights

Comment: @AloneTogether Thanks. Yes I have tried sample weights, it is still not giving good accuracy. And class weights are not for 3D tensors.